# Firing two terminals from a single bash script and both terminals output to two separate files

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

I have two separate commands to runs in two different terminals.

**Scenario1:** When I do it without the bash script 
**In terminal 1:** `./executable1 -param conFile > output1.txt` 
**In terminal 2:** `./executable2 -param conFile > output2.txt`

It works and writes the output in two separate file.

**Scenario 2:** This is where I use a bash script and have problem.
I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal -e "./executable1 -param conFile > output1.txt"
sleep 5 
echo "Fired first Command"
gnome-terminal -e "./executable2 -param conFile > output2.txt"
echo "Fired Second command"
```

**It neither creates output1.txt nor output2.txt**. **How do I achieve this?**

I tried one more thing :

```
./mybashscript.sh >output.txt
```

but it generates an output file whose contents are only:

```
Fired first Command
Fired Second command
```

I was expecting the output of the command1 and command2 and it only gives me the echo part of bash file.

But I need the output of both the commands in two different file.

**Note:** Among the two command first one is the receiver and second command is of sender. So,I have to open them one after another.

Comment: Why are you using `gnome-terminal`?  Do you have better success if you just background `bash`es?  `bash -e "./executable1 -param conFile > output1.txt" &`

Comment: I agree with @StephenNewell, except I would take it one step further, why fork another shell at all?  Why not just run two background processes in the current shell?  `./executable1 -param conFile > output1.txt & sleep 5; echo "Fired first Command"; ./executable2  -param conFile > output2.txt & echo "Fired Second command"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "./executable1 -param conFile > output1.txt"'
```

as you need bash for the redirection.